# "your users are out of order, click re-order to fix" - what exactly does this mean and why does it effect a programs ability to load?

Tags: windows-7, user-management, users, user-permissions

"your users are out of order, click re-order to fix" - what exactly does this mean and why does it effect a programs ability to load?

OS: Windows 7 64 bit ultimate edition

What does it mean when right-clicking on a file and clicking on security you see a message that says this "your users are out of order, click re-order to fix".

What exactly does it mean that users are out of order and how could this prevent a program from working properly? Please let me know if you need more info to answer this and I will provide it.

Thank you

Comment: Can you give a screenshot of this message? (If you punch "click re-order to fix" into Google, this question is the only hit. So I'm suspecting you either have some very unusual software installed or are misreading/miscopying the message.)

Comment: The order of user list entries is not relevant to SAM resolution or the ACL.  Also, I have never heard of this message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Windows ACLs are applied in a certain order to be effective. Back in the WinNT and Windows 2000 days, the command-line utilities to modify file-permissions could cause problems if you blindly added/removed things. For example, if you were granting a group Modify permissions when they'd previously been granted R/O, it would add a second ACL with Modify and the ACL *list* would still have both.

They've since fixed this in the command-line utilities. However, this means that the various other utilities over the years have had to be modified to handle the old-broken behavior, and that's the dialog you see when you encounter it.

It is safe to click 'Fix'.

Comment: Thanks! This makes perfect sense. I didn't mention it but users were given permissions via a script which used command line but in the same way as win xp. That must have done it. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

It means that the people using the system are not behaving correctly (usually with issues like [PEBKAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PEBKAC), [ID-10t](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ID-10t) or [layer 8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Layer_8) failures). These users are often not salvageable, and so you need to order new users from Microsoft to replace them in order to remove the errors and restore normal operation. Disposing of the old users can be a hassle however, since they do not have self-shutdown functionality. [RFC1097](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1097) can be useful if the interface protocol is telnet, but this isn't usually the case nowadays. One often has to resort to bruteforce methods, but [RFC3251](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3251) can be used to perform this remotely which helps to avoid the mess.

Comment: I have to admit... I couldn't stop smiling after this answer